# How to Call shared service function in angular 2 View?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to call a shared service function form "Another" component's view file.

For example to delete a record I want to set something like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ddata of tableData.data; let i = ddata" 
(click)="delete_record(ddata)" 
[class.active]="ddata.discountauthorizationid == selectedRow">
```

Here `delete_record` must be part of a service which I will inject in relavant component.

Comment: [typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way to call service from view (template) without injecting it into your component.

You can inject the service into a public property which lets you use the service methods inside the template as well.

```
constructor(public yourService: YourService) {

}
```

Your template:

```
<a (click)="yourService.yourMethod()">Test mehod</a>
```

**Note:** Please consider that the better solution is to call your component methods instead of using service methods. Services are a great way to share information among classes that don't know each other

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I can import it in my customer. My doubt was that can I call that from view or not. I will implement this and let you know.

Comment: @Jaydeep You're welcome, I'm glad if that helps. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: I used the above solution. Now I am able to call the injected service but I can do so only in constructor function.

Comment: Please don't inspire anyone to call service in template. It's not good practice

Comment: @Imran You're right. It's not a good way to use Services as component methods! I just added a new line to explain it. Thanks for letting me know your idea.

Comment: @Jaydeep: you have to call another method, do something and then call your service inside, this way the service is still hidden from the template.

Comment: @HDJEMAI Yes, that's also a way how you can implement this.

Comment: injecting the service as public in the constructor is really a bad idea here.

Comment: @HDJEMAI As long as I know it's not an anti-pattern. Please take a look at [this code snippet](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectable-and-nested-service-dependencies) on the official doc

Comment: anything marked as private cannot be accessed by the component's template. Accessing directly the service from the template can be a security issue.

Answer (score 5):

According to the official documentation, injecting public service to bind it in the template is not an anti-pattern.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: I'm yet to decide myself, but the fact it's good enough to be in the official docs (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#final-code-review - see the messages.component.html file) is reassuring!

Answer (score 2):

For good practice is good to use the service in `private` scope and use a method to return it to the view.

like in this post.

[Typescript dependency injection public vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private/57616943#57616943)

Comment: This is a better approach than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every property defined within the component class can be used in the template.

Comment: private injected service, cannot be accessed from the template.

Comment: Apparently you can access a private injected service from the template in version 7.1.4.