# Angular: Injection does not build in production build

Tags: angular, build, code-injection

I'm using Angular 5.1.1. I have an app with a navigation service which I inject into my components.

The Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  ...
}
```

The Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from './services/navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less'],
  providers: [NavigationService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App Title';
  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) { }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="navigationService.navigationModel != null">
  <app-navigation-head></app-navigation-head>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <app-navigation-side></app-navigation-side>
    </div>
    <div class="page-container">
      <app-data-page></app-data-page>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run the app with ng serve, everything is fine. Also when I build it with ng build. The injection works and the app is working fine.
But when I want to build it as production with ng build --prod I get the error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.html(1,6): : Property 'navigationService' is private and only accessible within class 'AppComponent'.

But why? Do I something wrong with the injection?

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private

Comment: If you are using the variable `navigationService` within your template file, then this is an error if you build using `aot`.

Comment: see this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978

Comment: Ah ok, if I change the service to public it works. Thank you!

Comment: Write answer to below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the answer for future readers.

If you are using the variable `navigationService` within your template file, then this is an error if you build using `aot`.

It is recommended but not necessary to build using `aot` for production. But when you do so, make sure your private variables are accessed only within the same `.ts` file. And not even from `.html` or template file.

Also check [this](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#current-status) to know what is allowed and what is not allowed in aot.