# Should I use readonly on injected Angular services instead of making them public?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I had a discussion today where some of my colleagues said that they inject their Angular services like that:

```js
constructor(readonly language: I18nService)
```

They said they do this because it prevents consumers of my component to change the injected service, kinda like that:

```js
@Component({ ... })
class ComponentA {
    constructor(public language: I18nService) {}
}

@Component({ ... })
class ComponentB {
    @ViewChild(ComponentA) compA: ComponentA;
    constructor() {
        this.compA.language = new I18nService();
    }
}
```

So, while technically they are right I'm still not convinced that I should do it that way. I ask myself the following question:

1. DI is a fundamental part of Angular. If someone really does this, should this person better run into this pit and fail or should he/she not be able to do this at all
2. `readonly` in this situation might be pretty complex to understand for someone who starts learning Angular and TypeScript for a couple of reasons

   - Angular doesn't use this approach in any of their official DI docs
   - You need to know how `readonly` works and that it just protects the reference of my injected service but none of the properties
3. In my opinion, it is a corner case problem, even though there's a simple solution to it

What do you think? Are there any official references I might not have seen? I haven't found anything when I tried to google for the usage of `readonly` in Angular concepts

One last word: While it is 100% true - It is possible to manipulate a reference of `public service: Service` - I'm still not sure if this should be solved at all and struggle whether to do it or not.

Comment: At risk of being closed for being opinion based, I'd suggest adding that you are looking for official references. I typically use `private: myService: MyService` to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I added this at the second-last paragraph! There really might be official references I haven't found yet.

Comment: I second @WilliamLohan. I always define services as `private` in the constructor.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that explicitly states it but I assume all the angular docs inject private bc DI gives that component the service for it alone and anything else should injects its own service. Also semi related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private

Comment: I usually make the service, and other injected items, private for encapsulation and high cohesion. The component should expose what is necessary for it to work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085285/1260204, this is not really specific to angular IMO.

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with readonly, just that only making it readlony doesn't solve the issue with the code above. If `ComponentB` is getting `I18nService` from `ComponentA` you are undermining DI and `ComponentB` becomes tightly coupled and could never be unit tested w/o `ComponentA`

Comment: Angular has `public` services in their docs https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action but I'm unsure if this is on purpose or just a documentation issue

Comment: The `readonly` doesn't actually make it readonly. It just means that Typescript will not let anyone external change it. `private` should accomplish the same thing. I think that the `private service: Service` is the way that we should stick here. 

I will add, if someone could show me an advantage of using the readonly, I would consider adopting it. But the reasons provided thus far is not a real reason.

Comment: My thoughts on it are that sometimes you want to use a DI service in the component template (to avoid writing a wrapper function for each piece you need). You have to mark it public to use it in a template. If you are making it public, someone could accidentally replace it (shame on them). But if you mark it readonly, this will remind future developers not to. However, I am also looking for evidence that this is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 9):

It is not something that you have to do, but it is good practice to make them `readonly` since you probably don't want to reassign the instance again.

> Read-only properties may have initializers and may be assigned to in constructors within the same class declaration, but otherwise, assignments to read-only properties are disallowed.

Answer (score 5):

you can add `private readonly service : ServiceClass`

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Whats the reason

Comment: The reason for this is to limit anyone from reassigning the same object reference within the class where it is injected. For example you have private someService: SomeService. Inside any other function than your constructor you can set someService to a new instance (someService = new SomeService()). The readonly will prevent this.