# Function passes only once in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a service that allows me to activate a button and see its status in the different components.
When I click start / pause, the button changes image.

In StackBlitz, the code works perfectly, but when I implement it in my project, the function only passes once in `ngOnInit` and no longer loads, no longer changing the image of the buttons between the components.

Is there a way to implement this but without using `ngOnInit`?

I used `setinterval` and the button changes the image, but it doesn't seem the best solution.

Can anyone help me?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mccwr?file=src/app/about/about.component.ts)

**Problem --- component about**

```
currentState: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this.currentState = this.servicesService.getCurrentState();
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn ">
            <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" src="https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/100/000000/play-button-circled.png">
            <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" src="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/stop-squared.png">
        </button>
        <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
            <li role="menuitem">
              <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="startTimer()">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem">
              <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="pauseTimer()">Stop</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <span>{{servicesService.fetchDisplay()}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
 startTimer() {
    this.servicesService.startTimer();
    this.currentState = this.servicesService.getCurrentState();
 }

 pauseTimer() {
    this.servicesService.pauseTimer();
    this.currentState = this.servicesService.getCurrentState();
 }
```

Comment: ngOnInit on component lifecycle runs only once. If you wan't to run something more than once, than you need to use setInterval etc. 
If you need to run it once, but after view is inited, then you can try ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Hello ! you actually need to use a state in different component, I'm not going to respond to your question but I wanted you to have a look to https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/ . NGRX can be a good alternative if you planned to use differents states in multiples components :) Just a blog that you should read if you don't know NGRX, If you still want to use this service patern I will suggest you to get your current state in the  *ngIf like this : *ngIf="this.servicesService.getCurrentState() === 'pause'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can define your service as public

```
constructor(public servicesService: ServicesService) { }
```

and in your html

```
*ngIf="servicesService.getCurrentState()=='pause'"
```

Comment: Afaik the service does not have to be public though to consume it in the same component.

Comment: @lama Please can you explain why? I would like to know why you think so.

Comment: Sorry, although it works with the JIT compiler, it is not with AOT. @AshotAleqsanyan is right, my mistake.

Comment: @lama If I correctly understand what you say. I have used this many times and compile project with --AOT, everything works as expected.

Comment: If you inject a "private" service, it does not work with AOT, but as you suggested "public" does. "private" would work as long as he would use the JIT compiler. That is what I mean. Here is a discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596546/4827723

Comment: @lama got it, thank you and sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

**component**

```
constructor(private servicesService: ServicesService) {}

public get isPlaying() {
   return this.servicesService.getCurrentState() === 'play';
}

public get isPaused() {
   return this.servicesService.getCurrentState() === 'pause'
}
```

**HTML**

```
*ngIf="isPlaying"
```

or

```
*ngIf="isPaused"
```

Comment: Thanks for trying help me, best regards !

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnInit` is a licefycle hooks and always runs exactly once. If you want to execute something everytime a value changes, you need a different hook. In your case probably `ngOnChanges`.

This one gets called everytime a component binding value changes.

For more information on the different hooks I recommend: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks