# Angular dependencies best practice - is it OK to reference ts file other than its component.ts in a component.html?

Tags: angular, dependencies

I recently had an argue with a friend from my team. We had this `experiment-row.component.html` file that had the following code:

```
*ngIf="experimentsPageService.isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)"
```

I argued that it's a bad practice that your html file will be dependent on any class other than its component.ts in our case `experiment-row.component.ts` and we can avoid it by creating

```
isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment) {
     return experimentsPageService.isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)
}
```

inside experiment-row.component.ts. He on the other hand side its a decorating function in the component file, which is not completely wrong. I searched a lot in [angular's styling guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) and did not find anything about that issue.

Is there any best practice for that issue? Is it OK that my component.html will know all my services?

and if there is any official resource please share it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts on this Topic:

> Is there any best practice for that issue? is it OK that my
> component.html will know all my services?

Your component depends on some service(s) since you inject them in the module of this component or the component itself. component.html hasn´t a dependency on such services but its depend of some objectstructe which is callable, eg "experimentsPageService.isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)". So the Template dont care if there is a real service behind experimentsPageService or just something like this:

```
public experimentsPageService = {isRegularStatusIconVisible:(x) => x}
```

So i think it really depends on personal preference.

**But there is another thing you should really care for**: Both of your calls are function-calls in a template, this can be seen as bad-practice because this methods are called every time the change-detection cycle runs (you can easy validate this via a `console.log` inside the function).

Comment: but regarding to the question, don't you think it adds an unnecessary dependency to the component.html file? about the other issue you are right I will change that thanks

Comment: as i wrote, i think its not. There is no difference in: `*ngIf="experimentsPageService.isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)"` vs
`*ngIf="isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)"`

Both versions depend on ONE variable in the template context to be there, both of them expect there is a callable path "experimentsPageService.isRegularStatusIconVisible(experiment)". For me its the same, except, in your version you habe more code to write

Answer (score 0):

A friend found a different question but with an answer just to that question.

[Typescript dependency injection public vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private/57616943#57616943)

can a manager mark as duplicated but keep the question?
because the question is hard to find as it asks something very different, but the answer is the exact one I was looking for.

edit:
this is code from angular tutorial:

```html
<div *ngIf="messageService.messages.length">

  <h2>Messages</h2>
  <button class="clear"
          (click)="messageService.clear()">clear</button>
  <div *ngFor='let message of messageService.messages'> {{message}} </div>

</div>
```

seems like although what it says angular does not define it as best practice as it does not use that pattern in the official documentation
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4.