# Angular public service

Tags: angular, service, private, public

I want to use a value coming from a service into my HTML.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  foo =  'Foo';
}
```

Most examples I found use private service

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{foo}}',
})

export class AppComponent {
  get foo() { return this.dataService.foo; }
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

I am wondering why not declare the service as Public to avoid the getter

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{dataService.foo}}',
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic encapsulation problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming). Best practice is to set services as private because each module has a role :

- Service provide utils functions
- Component use the service to perform operations

You can also check this topic for more information : [Typescript dependency injection public vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596399/typescript-dependency-injection-public-vs-private)